# Vagrant Private Networking

Tags: networking, vagrant, ansible, kubernetes

I am trying to create a Kubernetes cluster with Vagrant using an Ansible playbook that works perfectly on real (linux) servers. I am having a problem with the `kubeadm join` with vagrant.

I am using the following command to join a node to the cluster.

```
kubeadm join --token={{ kube_token.stdout }} {{ hostvars[groups['kubemaster'][0]].ansible_default_ipv4.address }}
```

The problem with vagrant is that it interprets:

`hostvars[groups['kubemaster'][0]].ansible_default_ipv4.address`

as the `enp0s3` address which seems to always be `10.0.2.15` on all machines in my cluster.

I have tried explicitly setting the ip of my machines using:

```
machine.vm.network :private_network, ip: < ip >, auto_config: false
```

but this sets the `enp0s8` address so it still doesn't work.

How do I make the `hostvars[groups['kubemaster'][0]].ansible_default_ipv4.address` different on all the machines in my vagrant setup?

Comment: the thing is that vagrant always specifies the 1st network interface as NAT with IP `10.0.2.15` so it knows it and uses that to ssh into the VM. In case of vagrant you'd need to read the IP from the 2nd network interface

Answer (score 1):

you can use `hostvars[groups['kubemaster'][0]].ansible_eth1.ipv4.address` 
assuming that your eth1 is your actual ip you want.  as noted by Frederic, it uses the default as the first.  you can do `ip addr` to find your interfaces on a machine.